# How to delete an element from an array in D

Tags: arrays, d

Concatenating an element `x` to an array `items` is easy in D, it's as if it were an array list:

```
arr ~= x;
```

but how do I *remove* an element at index `i` from `items`?

(Caveat: If I remove an element and then add a new element, the array **must not be reallocated**. So a simple slice won't work.)

---

#### Update:

Based on CyberShadow's answer about using `assumeSafeAppend`, I wrote this code:

```
static void removeAt(T)(ref T[] arr, size_t index)
{
    foreach (i, ref item; arr[index .. $ - 1])
        item = arr[i + 1];
    arr = arr[0 .. $ - 1];
    arr.assumeSafeAppend();
}
```

However, the problem happens when you have something like:

```
auto superArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; //Must not be modified
auto arr = superArr[0 .. $ - 1];
writeln(superArr);
arr.removeAt(0);    //Should copy the slice and modify the copy
writeln(superArr);  //but obviously doesn't
```

The base array of  slice should **not** be modified if an element is removed from the slice; instead, the slice needs to be copied.

But I have no way of knowing if an array is a slice of a bigger array... so that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated my answer with regards to your edit.

Comment: @CyberShadow: That is *so* hacky, but I'll use it anyway. xD Thanks!

Comment: @CyberShadow: Wait, actually, I just tried that and it didn't seem to work... are you sure that's what it does?

Comment: Works for me, but (as I just realized) it won't work if the slice is at the end of the array... never mind :/

Comment: This may be not my place to ask, but are you sure that this is sound from a design perspective? Checking if a T[] is a slice of a larger array is not a sure-proof way to ensure that you're not overwriting data also pointed by another reference. For example, even if you make sure to follow the convention that slice = aliasing, an algorithm using your code might pass arr[i..j] where i==0 and j==arr.length, and removeAt would be none the wiser. You may want to look into D's const-correctness capabilities to control aliasing.

Comment: @CyberShadow: Hm... but isn't `arr[i..j]` a slice of `arr`? So wouldn't it reallocate before removing? I don't understand the problem with when `j == arr.length`...

Comment: `arr[i..j]` where `i==0` and `j==arr.length` is `arr[0..$]`, which is completely identical to `arr`. Your method for checking if a `T[]` is a slice of a larger array will consider it as not a slice.

Comment: @CyberShadow: Oohh I see... argh, this is a *lot* uglier than I thought... :\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (Caveat: If I remove an element and then add a new element, the array **must not be reallocated**. So a simple slice won't work.)

The [`assumeSafeAppend`](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/object.html#assumeSafeAppend) function will tell the runtime not to reallocate the array when appending to it (i.e. it is an affirmation from the user that there aren't other slices which might be stomped by an append).

`remove` from [std.algorithm](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html) does an in-place remove. If you're using [std.container](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_container.html), there's also `Array.linearRemove`.

Comment: +1 for `remove`, albeit the last time I checked the implementation was a bit slow. I therefore often use `memmove` instead.

Comment: @CyberShadow: I don't think `remove` or `linearRemove` do the job (the first one would cause a reallocation on adding a new element, no? and the second one doesn't integrate with the language and the GC) but I *think* `assumeSafeAppend` is pretty helpful, I'll accept this if it works. :) +1

Comment: @CyberShadow: No, it seems like `assumeSafeAppend` is a little tricky: It only works if you're removing from an array that is *not* a slice of another array; otherwise, you could overwrite the super-array. Is there a way to detect if an array is a slice of a bigger array?

Comment: std.container.Array doesn't have `remove`. Not sure what exactly you're looking for when you mention language/GC integration, but std.container.Array is reference-counted, and overloads the index and slice operators.

Comment: @CyberShadow: If I store a pointer to the GC heap (e.g. object reference) inside my `Array`, how would the GC know to scan it? AFAIK `Array` can't just be substituted for a regular array like that.

Comment: Although it's possible, I don't think there is a function in the runtime to query whether an array is a slice of a larger array.

Comment: `Array` should work fine even if you store types with pointers. It will explicitly add the data to the list of additional memory ranges scanned by the GC: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/d1d81245ea26603980ca/std/container.d#L1606

Comment: @CyberShadow: Oooh I did not know that. In that case, it might work, but it'll only be a last resort, unfortunately. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 22):

Copying my answer on digitalmars.D (thanks for forwarding):

As has been mentioned, std.algorithm.remove can be of help. You may want to look at three of its capabilities in particular: (a) remove multiple offsets in one pass, e.g. remove(a, 0, 4) removes the first and fifth element, (b) you can remove subranges, e.g. remove(a, tuple(1, 3)) removes the second through fourth element, and (c) if you don't care about the order in which elements are left after removal you may want to look into unstable remove, which does considerably less work.

Andrei

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) Same comment as I posted on the newsgroup, though... `remove` either doesn't really seem to modify the array correctly (actually removing anything would still cause a reallocation on add). :\

Comment: How would you remove a set of indices? Such as 'remove(a, [0, 2, 3])'?

Answer (score 3):

Well if order is of no importance you can copy the last element to the location of removal then reduce the array length by one.

Comment: Sorry but order is of importance. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the first or last elements use slices:

```
array = array [1..$]
array = array [0..$-1]
```

Or a general way which works for a middle one as well:

```
array = array [0..unlucky] ~ array [unlucky+1..$]
```

If the elements aren't basic elements such as structs, floats, ints then arrays are implicitly arrays of pointers and this is an efficient operation.

Answer (score -6):

There's no automated way of doing this, you'll have to shuffle the array items along, reset .length and then catenate.